# Aws backup plan multiple selection_tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-backup

I have a question that I have been researching for a few hours now but still didn't manage to get a proper answer.

I'm defining an aws_backup_plan in terraform.

```
module "backup" {
  count  = var.backup_enabled ? 1 : 0
  source = "somwthing/backup/aws"
    
  enabled                  = var.backup_enabled
  version                  = "0.13.1"
  namespace                = "sr"
  stage                    = var.stage
  name                     = "storage-backups"
  tags                     = var.tags
  schedule                 = "cron(0 10 ? * * *)" # At 10:00 AM, daily
  iam_role_name            = local.iam_role_name  # unique role name per region as IAM resources are global
  delete_after             = 35                   # cannot be bigger than 35 days 
  enable_continuous_backup = true
  backup_resources         = var.backup_resources
  selection_tags = [
    { type = "STRINGEQUALS", key = "backup", value = "weekly" },
    { type = "STRINGEQUALS", key = "backup", value = "daily" }
  ]
}
```

I have just added `{ type = "STRINGEQUALS", key = "backup", value = "daily" }` to the `selection_tags`. My question is, if I tag one resource with one of the tags in the array does it get assigned the backup plan? I.e. does this array behave like an OR operator?

Comment: Could you share the link of your Terraform module used in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it depends on how condition was written, In this particular example it behaves like an `AND` statement rather an `OR`. This was designed to provide refined targeting mechanisms when creating plans.

Please take a look at this image from AWS backup:

[image]

Comment: Hum, that is actually a good point. My problem is that my current tag doesn't actually define what the backup plan does, and I already have a bunch of resources consuming it so I wanted a way of making this backwards compatible whilst I change the tag name without affecting the resources

Comment: Are you aware of a way of handling them as an OR operation?

Comment: @JorgeGuerreiro You many want to consider to just create a new backup plan while you slowly retag the pre-existing resources.

Comment: @JorgeGuerreiro, you can check the example from this Terraform module which offers multi-selection capability. https://registry.terraform.io/modules/lgallard/backup/aws/latest

Comment: I'll have a quick look and see if I can get my head around it, thanks :)

Comment: actually if you check on this one https://registry.terraform.io/modules/lgallard/backup/aws/latest/examples/selection_by_tags it seems it behaves like an OR